# UIButton won't hide/unhide

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I set  `UIButton` myButton to hidden on `viewDidLoad`

In a `splitviewcontroller` I have it so that when I click on a `tablecell`, certain items unhide which works great for my `textviews` but my button is giving me this:

> ERROR: member reference base type void is not a structure or union

Here is some snippet of code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {



        detailViewController.myButton.hidden= NO;
        detailViewController.textView1.hidden= NO;
        detailViewController.textView2.hidden= NO;

    }
```

in the .h file there is

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
```

in `DetailViewController` is where the button and `textviews` are declared as

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
    IBOutlet UITextView *textView1;
    IBOutlet UITextView *textView2;
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *myButton;


-(IBAction)myButtonPressed; 
@end
```

`IBAction` `myButtonPressed` in the `DetailViewController.m` is

```
-(IBAction)myButtonPressed{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    RootViewController *RVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Root"];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.RootViewController = RVC;


}
```

Anyone have any thoughts on why the button won't behave like the other two will? Is it because I gave it an `IBAction`??

Comment: Check the UIButton declaration. Its not in the proper way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button should be a IBOutlet and please correct it and update XIB references and you should be good.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton * myButton;
```

link this to UIButton is XIB if you are using one.

Comment: Thank you, what a careless mistake. I'm acceptingthis because it was posted before the latter comment!

Comment: However, my button now crashes and won't change to the storyboard...was this affected when I changed it to (nonatomic, weak)?  **I just checked, it's still crashing...any ideas on why?

Comment: Ah I actually fixed it, deleted a file by accident... thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You forget to Put `IBOutlet` at the first of button creation it should be

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton; OR
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

And give proper connection to `file's owner`.